# First cohomology group of an open set

Tags: differential-geometry

> Let $V$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Why do we have $H^1_{dR}(V) \cong \ker(\mathrm{curl})/\mathrm{im}(\mathrm{grad})$?

I'm trying to understand why can we make this kind of isomorphism. The definition says that $H^1_{dR}(V) = \ker(d_2)/\mathrm{im}(d_{1})$ so do we need to show that $\ker(\mathrm{curl})$ and $\ker(d_2)$ are isomorphic as well as $\mathrm{im}(\mathrm{grad}) \cong \mathrm{im}(d_{1})$?

Comment: You should specify that cohomology is with real coefficients. Also: Do you know de Rham cohomology?

Comment: Did you already learn about the relation between gradient and differential of a function? Ditto for Curl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in $\mathbb{R}^n$ you can identify 1-forms $\Omega^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and (n-1)-forms $\Omega^{n-1}(\mathbb{R}^n)$)  with vector fields with this trivial mapping:
$$
\omega(\mathbf{x})=\sum_{i=1}^n \omega_i(\mathbf{x}) \, dx_i \longleftrightarrow \vec{V_{\omega}}(\mathbf{x}) = (\omega_1(\mathbf{x}),\omega_2(\mathbf{x}),\dots,\omega_n(\mathbf{x}))
\\
\omega(\mathbf{x})=\sum_{i=1}^n \omega_i(\mathbf{x}) \, dx_1\dots \hat{dx_i}\dots dx_n \longleftrightarrow \vec{V_{\omega}}(\mathbf{x}) = (\omega_1(\mathbf{x}),\omega_2(\mathbf{x}),\dots,\omega_n(\mathbf{x}))
$$
in $n=3$, both 1-forms and 2-forms could be identified with vector fields. if we start from definition of de Rham Cohomology :
$$
H^1_{dR}(V) = \frac{Z^1V}{B^1V} = \frac{\{\omega \in \Omega^1(V) | d\omega=0 \}}{\{\omega \in \Omega^1(V) | \exists\alpha \quad d\alpha=\omega \}}
$$
so for $V \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ lets calculate these two subspaces, for $Z^1V$ :
$$
\omega \in \Omega^1(V)  \quad d\omega = d(\omega_1 dx+\omega_2 dy+\omega_3 dz) = \\(\frac{\partial \omega_3}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial \omega_2}{\partial z})dy \wedge dz + (\frac{\partial \omega_1}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial \omega_3}{\partial x})dx \wedge dz + (\frac{\partial \omega_2}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial \omega_1}{\partial y})dx \wedge dy =0\\
\leftrightarrow \nabla \times \vec{V_{\omega}} = 0 \Rightarrow \vec{V_{\omega}} \in ker(\text{curl})
$$
for $B^1V$:
$$
\omega =d \alpha \quad \alpha \in \Omega^0(V) \rightarrow \alpha \in C^{\infty}(V)
\\ d\alpha = \frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial y} dy + \frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial z} dz \leftrightarrow (\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial x},\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial y},\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial z}) = \nabla \alpha = \vec{V_{\omega}} \Rightarrow \vec{V_{\omega}}\in Im(\text{grad})
$$